# Could not resolve android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-architecture-components

I am trying to add `lifecycle:extensions` to my project but i can not make it work . Each time it shows error .

> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.0.

I have already read several threads but could not make it work by the answers given there. 
Project level gradle is:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
   google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And build.gradle is :

```
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.0"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.0"
```

How can i make it work? I am on Android Studio 3.1.2 . I also tried to import some github samples but same error occurred each time . Now its been 7 hours i have been busting my head on this.

Comment: Check you are gradle running in offline mode or not? To check this `Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build tools -> Gradle`

Comment: Offline mode is disable . I forgot to add it in question .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already added [`google()`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components#add_the_google_maven_repository) in the `Build.gradle` so, try adding the latest version:

```
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"
```

Also, go to:

```
File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build tools -> Gradle
```

And uncheck the option if it is checked to download from repository.

---

**In case it didn't help**, updating gradle to the latest version will help:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
}
```

Comment: **What a HORROR** . How the hell changing version worked ? Is that mean `1.1.0` is not available on maven. I changed it to  `1.1.1` just like you said and it worked . Can i have some explanation on this for future .

Comment: That's a good question too. The `1.1.0` version might not be available with the current Gradle versions so, as a experience, updating to the latest version will work at this point.

Answer (score 2):

I faced and fortunately solved this problem.

The solution is:
You should open the firebase_database flutter plugin's build.gradle
(project root >> Flutter Plugins >> firebase_database-3.1.0 >> android >> build.gradle) and you should change the last same lines according to the following:

from: 
`

```
if (!containsEmbeddingDependencies) {
  android {
    dependencies {
      def lifecycle_version = "1.1.1"
      compileOnly "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:$lifecycle_version"
      compileOnly "android.arch.lifecycle:common:$lifecycle_version"
      compileOnly "android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8:$lifecycle_version"
    }
  }
}
```

`

to: 
`

```
if (!containsEmbeddingDependencies) {
  android {
    dependencies {
      def lifecycle_version = "2.1.0"
      api "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version"
      api "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:$lifecycle_version"
    }
  }
}
```

`

I found this solution according to a TODO in the plugin's code and it refers to a github issue: https://gist.github.com/blasten/78e97b1d97a736d7e8dcc3f520cea3f0

It works perfectly for me and solves the exact same issue above.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I add these:

```
 implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
 implementation 'androidx.media:media:1.1.0'
```

some times you can new a project ,then compare it.

Answer (score 0):

You're using androidx artifacts, therefore the classes that used to be in android.arch.lifecycle are now in androidx.lifecycle as per the Migrating to AndroidX documentation.